Regarding the issue of ionic operation
I reinstalled the system and ran the command line to report this issue. Can a friend help me solve it
run “npm i”
run “ionic cordova run android -lc”
` A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.

Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':CordovaLib:classpath'.
Could not find com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3.`
Is there any missing plugin
Or missing corresponding plugins for Android Studio


[cordova] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[cordova] * What went wrong:
[cordova] A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.
[cordova] > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':CordovaLib:classpath'.
[cordova]    > Could not find com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3.
